# Is there a way to disable specific Spybot Immunization rules?

Tags: windows-7, spybot-sd

I've been having problems using a desktop sharing application, which I've traced to the Immunization protections applied via Spybot S&D. Specifically, the problem has been narrowed down to the rules in the `\SOFTWARE (Plugins)` categories under the Internet Explorer groups. Once I disable these Immunization categories, everything in the application works fine.

Each of these categories appears to include ~900 protections on the system. I suspect that the root cause of my problems could be narrowed down to just one, or perhaps a handful, of the settings that get applied in these categories. However, I can't find any options in Spybot S&D which would allow me to drill down to the individual protection rules and choose which to enable or disable.

Is there something I'm missing, or is this not a feature available via the GUI? If it's not strictly supported in the application, is there a way to work around it by manually editing some of its files or registry settings?

Spybot S&D version: 2.2.21.0
Spybot Start Center version: 2.2.21.129
Windows Ultimate x64